# Multiple sheets with different required value on an continuously updating powerBI

Tags: powerbi

I've been going on with this task for weeks and it seems like I'm not anywhere closer to my goal.

I've managed to make an excel that works but now I need to translate it to PowerBI. The goal is to upload the original CSV/Excel-file every month directly into Microsoft teams and that every "wrinkle" will be updated automatic and give us the result that we want without any manual labour. That's why I can't use my working excel-model.

I work with warranty claims, when a product has to be repaired and it's still under warranty time I have to claim the responsible party for the whole cost (all the material, labour cost and other expenses).

I have made a dummy google sheets with almost all the formulas that are being used in my excel except XLOOKUP (google sheets doesn't use XLOOKUP), because my suppliers also have priority (prio) and geo dependency of where we take the unit price for every repair.

Please take a look, also added a sheet with desired outcome in powerBI.

Blue is original data.
Orange are formulas.

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_nl2_Dgam7JDdyzX-urrO2AEXuCzhQkB1nogTLn2eA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to upload the original CSV/Excel-file **every month directly into Microsoft teams and that every "wrinkle" will be updated automatic** and give us the result that we want without any manual labour.

That is something that I do really often at work.

What is behind Microsoft Teams *files* tab is actually Sharepoint. Sharepoint folder are very easy to use in PowerBI.

There is a function in PowerQuery "Combine" that merges all the file in a folder into one big table. Given they all have the same format.

Comment: I know that it's possible to upload files every month and PowerQuery will make the right adjustment to be able to comprehend it. 

Problem still remains is how I can make the necessary formulas that I've made in my dummy table, into PowerBI. And get the result as shown on my last sheet in dummy table.